# Dynamically create FormPanel inside existing DIV

Tags: html, forms, gwt, formpanel

Is there a way to create dinamically a GWT FormPanel and place it inside an exising html `《div id=myContainer"》`  that can be accesed via `getElementById ()`?

Comment: you mean by native method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
RootPanel.get("myContainer").add(form);
```

?

(I suspect there's something else, preventing you to do just this, but you didn't say anything about it in your question)